# How to: remove object from array that has certain property value and crete new array as result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 227
[catid] => 10
)
[1] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 228
[catid] => 29
)
[2] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 229
[catid] => 11
)
[3] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 230
[catid] => 29
)
)
```

Now I try to remove some objects from array basing on catid:

```
foreach ($myarray as $item) {
    if ($myarray->catid != 29) unset($item);
}
```

But how to create new array from above foreach? Basically I want a new array that contain only objects with catid = 29:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 228
[catid] => 29
)
[1] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 230
[catid] => 29
)
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Getting the values with only a certain catid can be done using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php);

```
$filtered = array_filter($myarray, function($item){ return $item->catid === 29; });
```

but this will not remove the object from the original array.  To do both at the same time, you can just add the operation to your loop.

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->catid == 29) {
        $new_array[] = $value;
        unset($myarray[$key]);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

foreach() makes COPIES of the array elements you're iterating. Your unset() is unsetting the COPY, not the original.

You want

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
   if($val ...) {
      unset($arr[$key]);
   }
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `array_filter()` & `array_map()` like this

```
//$arr = your array;

$new_array = array_filter($arr, function($v){ return $v->catid == 29 ? $v : false; });
```

or

```
$new_array = array_filter(array_map(function($v){ return $v->catid == 29 ? $v : '';}, $arr));
```